How to Deploy YOLOv8 Model in Python Flask Backend on Heroku with Large Model Files?
I developed a mobile app for image detection and classification using a Python Flask backend and React Native frontend. I trained my YOLOv8 model using Google Colab and downloaded the best.pt and bestc.pt files for object detection and classification. I placed these model files in the backend folder (/backend/models/) of my Flask app.
I’m trying to deploy the backend on Heroku, but I’m running into issues because the file size of the models is large. When I try to deploy the app on Heroku, I get an error saying that it can't detect the ultralytics package. After installing ultralytics, the size of my application increases to 3GB, which exceeds the 500MB limit allowed in the free version of Heroku.
Without the models and ultralytics package, the backend size is just 10MB. Here's my folder structure for the backend:
├── backend/
│   ├── models/
│   │   ├── bestc.pt
│   │   └── best.pt
│   └── app.py

from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from ultralytics import YOLO
from PIL import Image, ImageOps
from flask_cors import CORS
import io
import os

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

# Load the models once during startup
yolo_model = YOLO('models/best.pt')  # YOLO model for object detection and cropping
classification_model = YOLO('models/bestc.pt')  # Model for classification

CONFIDENCE_THRESHOLD = 0.5  # Set a confidence threshold for valid detections

@app.route('/classify', methods=['POST'])
def predict():
    try:
        file = request.files['image']
        img = Image.open(file.stream).convert("RGB")  # Ensure it's in RGB format

        # Run YOLO for object detection
        detection_results = yolo_model(img)

        # Debugging: Print detection results
        print("Detection Results:", detection_results)

        # Check if any detections are made
        if len(detection_results) == 0 or len(detection_results[0].boxes) == 0:
            return jsonify({'message': 'No objects detected in the image.'}), 200

        # Filter to keep only the most confident detection above threshold
        best_box = max(detection_results[0].boxes, key=lambda box: box.conf)
        if best_box.conf < CONFIDENCE_THRESHOLD:
            return jsonify({'message': 'No valid snake detected. Please upload a clearer image.'}), 200

        box_coords = best_box.xyxy[0].tolist()  # Convert to list of coordinates
        print(f"Cropping coordinates: {box_coords}")  # Debugging: Print cropping coordinates

        cropped_img = img.crop(box_coords)  # Crop using bounding box coordinates

        # Add padding to the cropped image to prevent distortion
        padded_img = ImageOps.pad(cropped_img, (224, 224), method=Image.Resampling.LANCZOS)

        # Perform classification on the padded image
        classification_results = classification_model(padded_img)

        # Process the classification results
        predictions = []
        for result in classification_results:
            top_class = result.names[result.probs.top1]
            top_confidence = result.probs.top1conf.item()

            # If the classification confidence is below threshold, reject the result
            if top_confidence < CONFIDENCE_THRESHOLD:
                return jsonify({
                    'message': 'No valid snake detected. Please upload a clearer image.',
                    'class': top_class,
                    'probability': "{:.2%}".format(top_confidence)
                }), 200

            # Determine venom status
            venom_status = get_venom_status(top_class)

            # Format the probability as a percentage with two decimal points
            formatted_prob = "{:.2%}".format(top_confidence)

            # Append to predictions
            predictions.append({
                'class': top_class,
                'probability': formatted_prob,
                'venom_status': venom_status
            })

        return jsonify({'predictions': predictions}), 200

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {str(e)}")
        return jsonify({'error': 'An error occurred during processing.', 'details': str(e)}), 500

def get_venom_status(class_name):
    venom_status_map = {
        'Common Indian Krait': 'Venomous',
        'Python': 'Non-venomous',
        'Hump Nosed Viper': 'Venomous',
        'Green Vine Snake': 'Non-venomous',
        'Russells Viper': 'Venomous',
        'Indian Cobra': 'Venomous'
    }
    return venom_status_map.get(class_name, 'Unknown')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000)))


How can I deploy this Flask app on Heroku with a large model size (around 3GB) while staying under Heroku's free tier limit of 500MB?
Are there any best practices for managing large models when deploying on Heroku or any alternative cloud solutions for this problem?
